# How can I visualize a 3D volume with Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Similar to how there's [vol3d](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22940-vol3d-v2) for Matlab, how can I visualize a 3D-Array in Python? I'm currently working with Matplotlib but I'll take whatever works.

Comment: With matplotlib, there are some tricks to navigate through them quickly with arrows or mouse, as well as changing the axis.

See:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/matplotlib-3d-volumetric-data
https://github.com/pydicom/contrib-pydicom/pull/19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html) has some good API for 3D plotting in python

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend [K3D](https://github.com/K3D-tools/K3D-jupyter/tree/master):

> K3D lets you create 3D plots backed by WebGL with high-level API
>   (surfaces, isosurfaces, voxels, mesh, cloud points, vtk objects,
>   volume renderer, colormaps, etc). The primary aim of K3D-jupyter is to
>   be easy for use as stand alone package like matplotlib, but also to
>   allow interoperation with existing libraries as VTK.

It works best in Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for [mplot3d `plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots), which is part of `matplotlib`. Examples are provided in the link.